# Is Script task only method I can use to merge data from one data source to another

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

Scenerio - I am going to try to keep this simple as possible.

Datasource1 consists of data that is 24 hours, 7 days a week.
Datasource2 contains a table of Time Constraints for business hours that looks like this:

```
create table Dim.TimeSpecs
(
   TimeSpecSK   int not null identity(1000,1),
   TimeSpecAK   int not null,
   [WeekDay]    int not null,
   FromHour int not null, 
   FromMinute   int not null,
   ToHour       int not null, 
   ToMinute int not null,

constraint Ktsc_PK_TimeSpec primary key clustered (TimeSpecSK asc)
);
```

Two sets of data:

[image: dataset]

Datasource2 will also hold the aggregated data.

I want to use SSIS to merge and aggregate data by day filtering out the Time Constraints mapped out, instead of merging hourly data and then filter the time constraints on the report end.

I can only think of using the Script Task to do this. Even if that is possible, because I have to merge the data using an inner join that will parse the date.

This could even be some mad request. But I am hoping someone can offer their advice.

This is what I have and I am migrating to much data because it is aggregated by hour:
[image: current configuration]

This is my desired solution to mitigate how much data I store into Datasource2.

[image]

The issue is the Merge Join or Lookup Dataflow controls do not allow you to apply Expressions in order to filter by datepart function in order for me to filter data from data source 1 from time constraints found in data source 2. My thought is to use the Script Task and bring both datasource datasets into it and manipulate them as required and then spit it back into a table in Data source 2.

I appreciate the feedback, because this isn't typical problem/question. But others may have run into something like this before dealing with data stored as 24/7 but the report needs aggregate business hours. My main goal is to mitigate how much data I store in Datasource2

Comment: Maybe you make it to simple. I dont understand the question, do you need help creating the aggregate data?. You mention two tables and two set of data, but only see one of each. And dont understand your desire output. And why you want SSIS?

Comment: I need to use SSIS because each data source are on two different servers. I need help figuring out if a Script task is required or even possible to merge my datasets together and filter the data that comes from Datasource 1 from data in Datasource2. I hope that helps. Trust me this is a complicated problem that a lot of thought has been put in. Maybe I am not articulating the issue well enough.

Comment: Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I still dont understand the problem if you want joing two DataSources then why dont make a simple SAMPLE with `Source1 ( ID integer)` and `Source2 (ID integer)` instead of add that many column. Or you problem is create the script task. Or your problem is work with SSIS ? Can you see how vague this is?

Comment: I added diagrams that may help.

Comment: I concur, the question is rather confusing. That said, you might just need a LookUp component added into your data flow to identify if the data from server 1 is in the domain of server 2 and then either let it flow or not into server 2. Or, you might look at pushing all the data onto server 2 in a staging table and then performing an Execute SQL Task after the data flow completes to merge the data according to the business rules I don't understand

Comment: The issue is the Merge Join or Lookup Dataflow controls do not allow you to apply Expressions in order to filter by datepart function in order for me to filter data from data source 1 from time constraints found in data source 2. My thought is to use the Script Task and bring both datasource datasets into it and manipulate them as required and then spit it back into a table in Data source 2.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, because this isn't  typical problem/question. But others may have run into something like this before dealing with data stored as 24/7 but the report needs aggregate business hours. My main goal is to mitigate how much data I store in Datasource2.